# C# preprocessor define symbol based on environment variable

Tags: c#, attributes, preprocessor

I have some logic which is like this:

```
#define MYVAR
...
#if MYVAR
[Attribute1]
#else
[Attribute2]
#endif
```

I want to be able to switch the attributes applied to a method based on a environment variable
Like if the environment variable `MYVAR` is set, then actually define the symbol 'MYVAR' and vice-versa.

TBH I do not know if it is possible. If not any ideas how to overcome this? I can ofcourse add this in the method itself - the env. variable check, but I need the attributes because of reflection being executed.
I can create a custom `MyAttrbute(int mode)` but I cannot add a logic in its constructor to extract an env. variable, because it must be a constant expression.

Possible solutions:

- Like the first comment suggests,  I can read the env. variable in the custom attribute. Still there will be some nasty reflection left to do.
- Because I am working on Linux with dotnet commands, I can actually bundle my build command with pre-step `sed` command and add a dummy placeholder `{{define_myvar}}` to the top of the `.cs` file and replace it with either empty string or the full string based on env. variables. No reflection here, but not very elegant.

Comment: You can read the environment variable inside the attribute.

Comment: Ok, this is an option and add a public property to the custom attribute and do some nasty reflection. Still question remains if there is an easier way.

Comment: You can pass the environment variable to the compiler using your build script, but the identifier in your C# code will not go looking for an environment variable for you. Using code in the attribute is also wrong, as that will be evaluated at runtime, whereas `#if xxx` will be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: TBH not following how reflection and so on is involved. Can you explain your use case more, cause ATM it seems to be more x-y problem.

Comment: You could use a T4 template maybe, to define a global symbol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find a nice solution.
It was the [comment by Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70336885/c-sharp-preprocessor-define-symbol-based-on-environment-variable#comment124335305_70336885) which gave me the idea and little bit more searching in this [area](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2020/08/c-preprocessor-directive-symbols-from.html).

C# code:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if MYVAR
            Log.Information("MYVAR defined!");
#else
            Log.Information("MYVAR not defined!");
#endif
        }
```

Project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <DefineConstants>$(MyVar)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Commands:

```
dotnet build MyProject.csproj -p:MyVar=$MYVAR -c Debug
dotnet run --project=MyProject.csproj -c Debug --no-build
```

These commands also work (docker ready):

```
dotnet publish MyProject.csproj -c Release -p:MyVar=$MYVAR
dotnet MyProject.dll
```

**Explanation:**

If the env. variable `$MYVAR` is set to `MYVAR` just like in the C# code, the `dotnet build` will replace the csproj file with `<DefineConstants>MYVAR</DefineConstants>` and the preprocessor will evaluate     `#if MYVAR` to true.

If environment variable `$MYVAR` is not set (aka empty string) or set to any other **different value** from `MYVAR`, the preprocessor will evaluate the condition to false.

IMO this is a very nice tweak which is suitable for different scenarios. Thanks for the guidance, guys. Cheers.

**Note:**

Like stated in the question I do not care about the value of the environment variable, only if it is defined or not, i.e. it is either empty string or not. Also the c# code is just PoC so it was easier to use logging instead of writing the attributes and the refraction.